# Python - Computing the number of days between two dates

Tags: function, datetime

I want to write a function called days_between that takes six integers (year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2) and returns the number of days from an earlier date (year1-month1-day1) to a later date (year2-month2-day2). If either date is invalid, the function should return 0. To be able to see if a given date is valid I wrote a function called is_valid_date as bellow:

```
def is_valid_date(year, month, day):
ndays = mdays[month] + (month == February and isleap(year))
if datetime.MINYEAR <= year <= datetime.MAXYEAR:
    if 1 <= month <=12:
        if 1 <= day <= 31 and 1 <= day <= ndays:
            return True
        else: return False
else: return False
```

if date is valid it returns True, if invalid it returns False.
In my days_between function I want to first check if the dates are valid and return the number of days between them if so. If the dates are invalid it returns 0. Also if the second date is earlier than the first date, the function should return 0.
This is what I have done:

```
def days_between(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
     date1 = date(year1, month1, day1)
     date2 = date(year2, month2, day2)
     diff = date2 - date1
     if is_valid_date(year1, month1, day1) and is_valid_date(year2, month2, day2):
          return diff
     elif date2 < date1:
          return 0
     else: 
          return 0
```

now when testing this function with date:

```
print(days_between(2026, 1, 3, 2025, 6, 3))
```

it returns a negative number -214 days, 0:00:00 when its suppose to return 0 since second date appears before. Further if I test with a invalid date:

```
print(days_between(2026, 1, 34, 2025, 6, 3))
```

it returns a error message when its suppose to return 0 since it is an invalid date:

```
 line 39, in days_between
 date1 = date(year1, month1, day1)
 ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

Can someone help me validate this function and if something is wrong in my code which I can't see please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

After several trials I have used the calendar library to be able to find the results. Here is the code:

```
def is_valid_date(year, month, day):
    try:
       days = calendar.monthrange(year, month)
       days1 = days[1]
       if datetime.MINYEAR <= year <= datetime.MAXYEAR:
           if 1<= month <= 12:
              if 1<= day <= days1:  
                  return True
              else:     
                  return False
       else: return False
    except ValueError:
       return False
```

to find out the difference among to dates that's what I did:

```
def days_between(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    try:
        date1= datetime.date(year1, month1, day1)
        date2= datetime.date(year2, month2, day2)
        dif = date2 - date1
        diff = dif.days
        if diff < 0:
            return 0   
    except ValueError:
        return 0
    else: 
        return diff
```

If someone has another methodology please do share with me.